# Get EntityManager in Helper Class

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I´m using Symfony 2.1, I have this controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\UsuariosBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use app\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuarios;
use app\ClientesBundle\Entity\Clientes;

use app\UsuariosBundle\Util\Util;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    //Some functions

    public function conexionAction(Request $request){
        $util=new Util();
        $sesion=$util->compruebaSesion(1,1,1);

    }
}
?>
```

And this is my helper class, his folder is in UsuariosBundle\Util\Util.php

```
<?php
namespace app\UsuariosBundle\Util;

class Util
{   
    public function compruebaSesion($tipo,$idUsuario,$login){
        //Here I need the entity manager
    }
}
?>
```

I need the entity manager to do some updates in the database with the util class from everywhere in the app, but I don´t know how to get the entity manager here,out of the controller.

**|-| UPDATE |-|**

I have updated my code with the instructions of Vincent T and I´m gettin this error:

"Argument 1 passed to app\UsuariosBundle\Service\Util::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, "

app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    util:
        class:        app\UsuariosBundle\Service\Util
        arguments:    ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

src/UsuariosBundle/Service/Util.php

```
<?php
namespace app\UsuariosBundle\Util;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Util
{   
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
      $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function compruebaSesion($tipo,$idUsuario,$login){
        $query= $this->em->createQuery('some query');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: define your Helper Class as a Service and inject the Entity Manager

Comment: Where do I must define the service?In app/config/config.yml or UsuariosBundle/Resources/config/services.yml?

Comment: @SensacionRC You do not need to create a new instance of the class, in the since it will be instantiated for you, all you need to to is replace the `new Util()` by `$this->get('util')`. I also recommend using a better name for the service like 'app.service.util'

Comment: I´m still with the error or the argument 1 passed to __construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager

Comment: Can you update the code

Comment: AS you see under the UPDATE text,this is my actual code and I´m getting the error

Comment: @SensacionRC I have update my answer and added the controller class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service as described in the docs [sf docs services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)
and then you can just either inject that as a base service or get it using `$this->get('name_of_helper_service')` in a controller.

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
   app.service.util:
       class:        app\UsuariosBundle\Service\UtilService
       arguments:    ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

helper class

```
<?php
namespace app\UsuariosBundle\Util;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Util
{   
    /**
     * @Var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
      $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function compruebaSesion($tipo,$idUsuario,$login){
        $query= $this->em->createQuery('some query');
    }
}
?>
```

Controller class

```
<?php

namespace app\UsuariosBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use app\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuarios;
use app\ClientesBundle\Entity\Clientes;

use app\UsuariosBundle\Util\Util;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    //Some functions

    public function conexionAction(Request $request){
        $util= $this->get('app.service.util'); 
        $sesion=$util->compruebaSesion(1,1,1);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry,your code now works,it was a cache problem,I cleaned and now it works,thanks

Comment: @SensacionRC No problem glad i could help.